# SELECT INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to insert data from select statement into a a dynamically created table? I will not know how many columns are there in select statement until I run the query. It has to create the appropriate number of columns at run time.
Thank you,
Smith

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `SELECT INTO` syntax:

```
SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM MyTable
WHERE ...
```

The new table `NewTable` will be created with the same columns as your select statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637925/dynamically-create-and-load-table-from-select-query is the updated question. Becasue all the answers gets the data from a table. In my case I get data from  complex expression.

Comment: You ideally should have updated this question instead of creating a new question; it causes confusion when multiple people are working on the same problem over multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTAS pattern for this

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO    
----Create new table and insert into table using SELECT INSERT
SELECT FirstName, LastName
INTO TestTable
FROM Person.Contact
WHERE EmailPromotion = 2
----Verify that Data in TestTable
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM TestTable
----Clean Up Database
DROP TABLE TestTable
GO
```

Have a look at [This Article on CTAS](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/30/sql-server-ctas-create-table-as-select-what-is-ctas/)

Answer (score 0):

-- This creates temporary table

select * 
into #newtable 
from YourTable

select * from #newtable

-- This creates physical table in the DB

select * 
into newtable 
from YourTable

select * from newtable